# MySQL (phpMyAdmin) set default value for all columns in one MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, default

I have more than 300 columns in around 60 tables. Updating each column to a default value of '0' manually makes no sense. Is there a procedure that can change the default value for columns, currently 'NULL', in one table to a default value of '0' for each column in a table? repeating this task 60 times is not such a big deal since it will be done once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my column titles were programatically generated, I was able to regenerate all the column titles and therefore use that to generate MySQL statements to alter each of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: alright, is it possible with MySQL statements? :) looking for a solution here

Comment: The ALTER TABLE statement requires to specify the column so you would have to issue one such statement per column. Unless you can programm atically generate those statements.

Comment: good thing I have the columns programmatically generated, so I can regenerate their titles again and with that generate a SQL statement that updates each column. Tried and it worked perfectly